# How to remove gridlines on select cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I know I can select a range in Excel, apply a background/fill color and it works, not on Google Sheets. How can it be done?

[image: How do I get select cells to be like col. H? IMAGE]

Comment: just paint them white

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're asking for something like this, then google sheets doesn't have exact feature but we can achieve it

[image: output image]

Go to borders select [image: all border] **"All Borders"** then go to **"Border Color"** [image: border color] and choose white color.

Answer (score 1):

To turn off visible gridlines in the whole sheet, there is a menu option: View - Gridlines.

If you mean the borders around cells, like this:
[image]

there is the "Border" icon, as seen in the image above.

If you mean to fill in a colour, in a range of cells, there is the "paint bucket" icon, just to the left of the Borders icon, as seen in the center here:
[image]

Your question text does not match your question title.  Please clarify the question and/or the title.

Comment: Thank you so much, but not borders. I'd like to turn off select gridlines instead of all, like View - Gridlines does.

Comment: So does turning off View - Gridlines do what you want?  Or do you still have a question?  If so, please provide a sample sheet, SHARE with everyone, showing what you want to change.

Comment: It doesn't. I'll add the image. Thank you!